# Recognize if a cell is a fractional value within a range based on a certain condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using an Excel formula, I want to recognize for W, X, Y, and Z in Column A if ANY of their corresponding cell values in Column B contains a fractional value. Desired results are in column C, and the result with my formula is in column D. TRUE=Fraction, FALSE=Whole number

My formula fails to recognize that X has two fractions (0.1 and 0.9) because the addition of corresponding values in column B (0.1, 1, 2, and 0.9) is a whole number. However, it accurately recognizes that one of the values for Y is a fraction because the addition of corresponding values in column B for Y is not a whole number.

My formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SUM(IF($A$2:$A$12=A2,$B$2:$B$12))/ROUND(SUM(IF($A$2:$A$12=A2,$B$2:$B$12)),0)=1,0,1),0)=1
```

| Column A | Column B | Desired Result | Result with my formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 0.1 | TRUE | FALSE |
| X | 1 | TRUE | FALSE |
| Y | 0.7 | TRUE | TRUE |
| X | 2 | TRUE | FALSE |
| Y | 5 | TRUE | TRUE |
| Z | 8 | FALSE | FALSE |
| X | 0.9 | TRUE | FALSE |
| Z | 3 | FALSE | FALSE |
| Y | 4.1 | TRUE | TRUE |
| Z | 2 | FALSE | FALSE |
| W | 0.6 | TRUE | TRUE |

Unfortunately, VBA is not an option.

Comment: Not sur why 1 is fractional, so is 2 and 5 - what is your defition of "fractional" ? is this whether the number is real (all are rational numbers, you don't have sqrt (2) - or whether first decimal place is non-zero (e..g 0.1, 0.9) ? I don't get why desired result can be "False" and "True" for 2 at the same time - surely your desired result column in incorrect (inconsistent at best) - see that you have Z, 2, False (2nd last row) but then X,2, True (4th row) ??

Comment: I have assumed that "fractional" means "not whole number", i.e. first decimal place is "not zero" - in which case the function you have used appears way too complex - try function below (recognise that this is an array function, so you only enter it in a single cell, it will populate the rest of the cells for you - if you enter in the leading cell and then drag it down - you'll get !Spill# errors (assuming you're using Office 365 compatible version Excel)...

Comment: This should work : `=SUM(($A$2:$A$12=A2)*$B$2:$B$12)-SUM((INT($B$2:$B$12)*($A$2:$A$12=A2)))<>0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=SUM(($A$2:$A$12=A2)*$B$2:$B$12)-SUM((INT($B$2:$B$12)*($A$2:$A$12=A2)))<>0
```

---

Or, you can use `LET()` function just that the range is not repeated multiple times.

```
=LET(
    x, $A$2:$A$12,
    y, $B$2:$B$12,
    SUM((x = A2) * y) -
        SUM(
            (INT(y) * (x = A2))
        ) <> 0
)
```

---

Another alternative using `MOD()` & `MAX()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=MAX(($A$2:$A$12=A2)*MOD($B$2:$B$12,1))<>0
```

---

Using `LET()`

```
=LET(
    x, $A$2:$A$12,
    y, $B$2:$B$12,
    MAX(
        (x = A2) * MOD(y, 1)
    ) <> 0
)
```

---

You can use `BYROW()` as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=BYROW(
    A2:A12,
    LAMBDA(m,
        MAX(
            (m = A2:A12) *
                MOD(B2:B12, 1)
        ) <> 0
    )
)
```

---

Comment: All worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
=NOT(INT(B2:B12)=B2:B12)
```

[image]

PS : desired result for cell C3 should be False - i.e. this is NOT fractional.

Comment: C3 should be true because A3 = "X", and at least one other row with "X" in Column A has a fractional value in Column C.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

FILTER to look at all rows with the same letter in Column A

CHOOSECOLS to look at only the value in the 2nd column

MOD to keep only the fractional values

OR to test whether any of the rows have a fractional value

```
=OR(MOD(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER($A$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12=A2),2),1)>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use SUMPRODUCT to check if the sum of all values in column B from specific value in column A is different that sum of all **integer** values in column B for specific value in column A.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$12=A2)*$B$2:$B$12)<>SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$12=A2)*INT($B$2:$B$12))
```